# How to search a single cell with multiple values

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to search a JSON. Right now it functions with an exact match. I want to add multiple data to one cell - it'll look like this: "data, data2, nope, nope2". If a user searches 'data' it needs to match for data and data2.

this is the json:

```
[
{"car":"Mercedes, Toyota, KIA", "state":"SA", "groupName":"AHG"},
{"car":"BMW","state":"NSW","groupName":"Brighton BMW"},
{"car":"Tesla","state":"VIC","groupName":"JAMES F"},
{"car":"Audi","state":"WA","groupName":"Audi CBD","groupPhone":"1300 04"},
{"car":"Mercedes","state":"SA","groupName":"AHG","groupPhone":"1300 05"}
]
```

eg the 1st string of- "car":"Mercedes, Toyota, KIA" I need to return results if a user searches for Toyota. Right now it only works if the string is only "car":"Toyota"

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        addCar: false,
        cars: [],
        loading: false,
        searchCar: "",
        searchState: ""
    },
    methods: {
        search: function () {
            app.loading = true;
            var searchQuery = {
                car: encodeURIComponent(app.searchCar)
            };
            if (app.searchState) {
                searchQuery.state = app.searchState;
            };
            Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/a4d7192e71fd", {
                search: searchQuery
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                app.cars = data;
                app.loading = false;
            },
                function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    app.cars = [];
                    app.loading = false;
                });
        },
        
         
        
    }

})
```

Would be amazing if a user can search for Toyota and be delivered results for any string containing Toyota as a car :)

Comment: Max, are you looking for a client side function to do this filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple client-side search can be implemented by passing a regular expression object to the `String#match` method, where the pattern of the regular expression is your query/search string:

```
/* Returns non-null result is "query" matches any part of item.car string */
return item.car.match(new RegExp(query, "gi"))
```

You could combine this with `Array#filter()` to aquire only items for your JSON where the `car` field contains the query string:

```js
const json = [
{"car":"Mercedes, Toyota, KIA", "state":"SA", "groupName":"AHG"},
{"car":"BMW","state":"NSW","groupName":"Brighton BMW"},
{"car":"Tesla","state":"VIC","groupName":"JAMES F"},
{"car":"Audi","state":"WA","groupName":"Audi CBD","groupPhone":"1300 04"},
{"car":"Mercedes","state":"SA","groupName":"AHG","groupPhone":"1300 05"}
]

const findItem = (data, query) => {

  return data.filter(item => {
    
    return item.car.match(new RegExp(query, "gi"))    
  });
}

console.log("Search for Toyota", findItem(json, "Toyota"));
console.log("Search for Mercedes", findItem(json, "Mercedes"));
console.log("Search for Tesla", findItem(json, "Tesla"));
console.log("Search for Honda", findItem(json, "Honda"));
```

#### Update

To integrate the code snippet shown above with your Vue component, try this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    addCar: false,
    cars: [],
    loading: false,
    searchCar: "",
    searchState: ""
  },
  methods: {
    search: function() {
      app.loading = true;
      var searchQuery = {
        car: encodeURIComponent(app.searchCar)
      };
      if (app.searchState) {
        searchQuery.state = app.searchState;
      };
      Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/a4d7192e71fd", {
        search: searchQuery
      }).then(function(data) {

          /*
          Add code here
          */
          data = data.filter(item => {
            return item.car.match(new RegExp(app.searchCar, "gi"))
          });

          app.cars = data;
          app.loading = false;
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          app.cars = [];
          app.loading = false;
        });
    },
  }

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've tried applying this to my code but think I'm maybe too much of a newbie to know where to put it :/ Could you help with where it would go in my code block?

Comment: @MaxGraham not a problem - not sure I fully understand how you would like to integrate the search for a single cell however if you have a look at the code under that Update heading, hopefully that gives you some clues on how to make use of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let arr = [{"car":"Mercedes, Toyota, KIA", "state":"SA", "groupName":"AHG"},{"car":"BMW","state":"NSW","groupName":"Brighton BMW"},{"car":"Tesla","state":"VIC","groupName":"JAMES F"},{"car":"Audi","state":"WA","groupName":"Audi CBD","groupPhone":"1300 04"},{"car":"Mercedes","state":"SA","groupName":"AHG","groupPhone":"1300 05"},{"car":"Toyota, Testing function", "state":"SA", "groupName":"AHG"}]

let selectedKey = 'car'
let selectedValue = 'Toyota'

let op = arr.filter(({[selectedKey]:key})=> key && key.includes(selectedValue))

console.log(op)
```